# Error while uploading content for Google Assistant Actions

Tags: google-sheets, chatbot, google-assistant-sdk

While trying to upload the content via Google Sheets URL I am getting the following error:

```
Authentication failure. Parameter: popup_blocked_by_browser
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Thanks after removing popup blocking was still seeing the error... Also removed empty rows with notes from the sheet. This resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Removing blank rows with notes from the sheet resolved the problem.

Comment: The rows at the top of the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off pop-up blocking and it worked.

To turn off pop-up blocker, follow these instructions:

1. Click the Customize and control Google Chrome menu (the three
   horizontal bars in the upper right corner)
2. Select Settings.
3. Click the Show advanced settings... at the bottom.
4. Under Privacy, click the Content Settings button.
5. To disable the pop-up blocker check the Allow all sites to show
   pop-ups box.
6. To enable pop-ups on specific sites, check Do not allow any site to
   show pop-ups (recommended) and click Exceptions and enter the
   URL(s).
   This helped me to resolve this issue